# jquery live search and pagination combined

Tags: jquery, search, pagination, combinations

I got a simple question, but for someone who struggles with even basic js, this is rocket science. I have downloaded two very basic scripts: one is a live search, the other one is a pagination script. They both act on a table with some data in it. Everything works as expected, except that when I delete a search term, instead of reverting back to a paginated table, I'm being shown all records. The scripts used are here:

https://www.codexworld.com/jquery-live-search-filter-on-html-table/

https://github.com/wikiti/jquery-paginate

They're perfect for my simple application, but I don't know how to make the table revert to a paginated one once I delete my search term. This is the code I use:

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dataSearch').on('keyup',function(){
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $('#carriersTable tbody tr').each(function(){
            var linestr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if(linestr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                $(this).hide();
            }else{
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
});

$('#carriersTable').paginate({ limit: 2 });
</script>
```

I tried moving the last line around (all possible combinations), but it just generates countless pagination links with each search :).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion. It could probably be optimised but it shows the idea.

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dataSearch').on('keyup',function() {
        // Get the search searchTerm
        var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

        // Prepare a "state" array to store rows you need to get back to
        var state = [];

        // Use the each loop with "key" as index iterator parameter
        $('#carriersTable tbody tr').each(function(key, value) {
            var linestr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            if (linestr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1) {
                $(this).hide();
            } else {
                // Here you store the row in state variable since you want to show it later
                state.push($(this));

                // Show the row for the current display
                $(this).show();
            }
        });

        // Now, you have a state var containing all the rows previously shown
        console.log(state);

        // You can create an event to detect when the search box is empty, and restore the state
        if (searchTerm.length == 0) {
            // Then you restore the state array after turning it into a string
            var restored = state.join('');

            // Empty the table and add the string
            $('#carriersTable').empty().append(restored);

            // You might need to refresh your pagination here, depends on your plugin :)
        }
    });
});
</script>
```